# Issue using The Task Scheduler with cmd

Tags: windows-10, scheduled-tasks, command-prompt

Can Windows 10 The `Task Scheduler` run `Reg.exe` commands from `command prompt`?

When I past this command to make changes in `reg.exe` in `CMD` -- its works! But not works at `Task Scheduler`!

```
Reg.exe add "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\Personalize" /v "SystemUsesLightTheme" /t REG_DWORD /d "0" /f"
```

*able to scheduler* **but not work command line** (trying scheduler work at 18 PM)

```
schtasks /create /sc daily /tn "Tema" /tr "Reg.exe add "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\Personalize" /v "SystemUsesLightTheme" /t REG_DWORD /d "0" /st {hora} /f
```

deleting command thas *works* too

```
schtasks /delete /tn "Tema" /f
```

I *able* to *Create* and *Delete* it as well, **but** I can't make it runs appropriately **from** `Task Scheduler` -- **nothing happens!**

Comment: I am afraid that there is a problem while you are adding the `schtask` command. As far as I know (personal experience) when the task is added to taskScheduler does not guarantee that the task scheduler is able to make it run. Last time I fixed my code where I create the scheduled task part, then it works fine.

Comment: PS. the fix that I am done last time was about the apostrophe/quote symbol `"`. There is an inconsistent number of apostrophes